# Convert php timestamp to actionScript

Tags: actionscript

How can I convert a php timestamp to something that is usable in actionScript? For example, how could I use the following timestamp? 
2011-06-16 10:41:08
The timestamp is currently stored in xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Marc B's answer is correct. If for some reason you can't use the PHP timestamp (number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970), you can try the static method `Data.parse()`.

It will return the number of miliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 based on your time string. It will process various time string formats, [here's a link to the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#parse%28%29).  You might have to tweak your time string into one of these formats (using a regular expression on the Actionscript side, or by generating a different string on the PHP side).

Once you get the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970, you can then create a new Actionscript `Date` object from that:

```
var date:Date = new Date( Date.parse(myTimeString) );
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a PHP timestamp, it's just a formatted string. PHP timestamps are the same as unix timestamps - an integer representing seconds since Jan 1/1970.

Actionscripts timestamps are the same, but in milliseconds. So take a native PHP timestamp, multiply by 1000, and there's your AS timestamp.